Efficient numerical calculation of Campbell's lemma
Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices. Consider Campbell's identity:
$e^{A} B e^{-A} = \mathbb{1} + [A, B] + \frac{1}{2!}[A,[A,B]] + \frac{1}{3!}[A,[A,[A,B]]] + \frac{1}{4!}[A,[A,[A,[A,B]]]]+ \dots$
This can be calculated iteratively term by term. However, that is not necessarily the most efficient method.  Of course, this is a form of matrix exponentiation, so defining the linear map $\mathsf{A} \circ B \equiv [A, B]$, we have
$e^{\mathsf{A}} \circ B = \mathbb{1} + \mathsf{A} \circ B + \frac{1}{2!}\mathsf{A}^2 \circ B + \frac{1}{3!} \mathsf{A}^3 \circ B + \frac{1}{4!} \mathsf{A}^4 \circ B + \dots$.
Because of this, I expect that there should be insight to be gained from efficient routines for matrix exponentiation, though direct exponentiation of $\mathsf{A}$ is out of the question because it is too memory inefficient.
Are you aware of efficient numerical methods that were developed specifically to compute the right-hand side for a given matrix $B$? I feel like I've seen this before, but a cursory look yielded little. There is a lot of work on calculated the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula, but that's not quite the same thing.
